# How to convert string as YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:SS:sss into epoch time?

Tags: math, time, epoch

I have a string as YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:SS:sss (ex : 2017-10-11:04:36:26.376). Now I want to convert it into epoch time . What would be programmatic approach for this ?
I am programming in C++, able to extract information in variable.

Comment: This is almost certainly implemented as an algorithm, not a formula. Any formula would need to be very long to cover all the cases, and would need to have many conditionals. How do you want the conditionals to be implemented--as piecewise defined functions? They would be deeply nested and the whole thing would look a mess. Why do you need a formula rather than code? Finally, what have you tried?

Comment: Not a linux guy but by epoch time you mean the same definition as TAG or Astronomical Epoch time as those are not the same. There are formulas for the days per year and winter/summer time switch dates but you need to iterate from some known time until you hit the desired time... You can speed up by incermenting with large steps ... then smaller and smaller until day barrier is hit.

Comment: @Spektre In Unix land, the epoch is `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`

Comment: The approach to this would vary massively depending on the language you are working on, even if you don't use a built-in function that already does it. You can't do maths on a string, so before you can use any kind of formula, you need some string parsing, for a start. Without a specific language or some constraint of what kind of algorithm you're looking for, there are far too many right answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said the formula is so complex and would make whole code a mess, So to avoid these I am **calculating the number of days from Input date to 01-01-2000**. As I know epoch time till 01-01-2000, thus by finding number of days considering leap year I can calculate total epoch time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a formula, but it's fairly ugly. I originally implemented something similar in BASIC 2.0 in 1982 (when each byte counted), and later converted it to Perl:

```
sub datestar { 
 $_=shift;
 /^(....)(..)(..)/;
 $fy=($1-($2<3)); 
 $jd=$fy*365+int($fy/4)-int($fy/100)+int($fy/400)+int(((($2-3+12*($2<3))*30.6)+.5)+$3); 
 return(86400*($jd-719469))
}
```

Note that this takes something like "20171011", not "2017-10-11", and doesn't convert hours/minutes/seconds (which are easy to convert).

As always, doublecheck code before use, and use it as a template to write your own code if you really want to.

However, you would be infinitely better off using your programming language's existing functions to do this.